# Show that $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=f(Ax+b)$ satisfies $g\in C^{1,1}_\tilde{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $\tilde{L}=||A||^2L$.

Tags: optimization, continuity, nonlinear-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Let $f\in C_L^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^m)$, and let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Show that the function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=f(Ax+b)$ satisfies $g\in C^{1,1}_\tilde{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\tilde{L}=||A||^2L$.

**My Attempt**

Given that $f\in C^{1,1}_L$, we know that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$. If we want to show that $g\in C_\tilde{L}^{1,1}$ then we have to show that $|f(Ax+b)-f(Ay+b)|\leq \tilde{L}|x-y|=||A||^2L|x-y|$ so we want to show that $\frac{|f(Ax+b)-f(Ay+b)|}{||A||^2}\leq |f(x)-f(y)|$.

I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction. Can I get some pointers on how to approach this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is $\tilde{L}=\lVert A\rVert^2L$ and not $\tilde{L}=\lVert A\rVert_2L$ or something like that?

Comment: @NicolásVilches Yeah. It's $\tilde{L}=||A||^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, the multivariate chain rule yields $\nabla g(x) = A^{T} \nabla f(Ax + b)$. From there,

$$
\| \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) \| =
\| A^{T} (\nabla f(Ax + b) - \nabla f(Ay + b)) \| \leq
\| A \| \| \nabla f(Ax + b) - \nabla f(Ay + b) \|,
$$
using the identity $\|A v \| \leq \|A\| \| v \|$. Finally, use the Lipschitz continuity of $\nabla f$ to get the claimed result.

Comment: I added a picture of the problem I am trying to solve above. I don't think I made any typos. It is from the book "Nonlinear optimization for theory, algorithms and applications" by Amir Beck

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the definition of the class $C_{L}^{1,1}$ in your original post? I don't have access to the book so I can't search for it.

Comment: $C_L^{1,1}$ is the class of functions with Lipschitz gradient with constant $L$. I included a picture in the original post with a little more context.

Comment: In that case, your original argument contains a mistake. If $f \in C_{L}^{1, 1}$ you should not have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L \| x - y\|$, but $\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \leq L \| x - y \|$.